# Saving a dark-themed plot using ggsave() creates white bordering panels

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio

I need my charts to have a dark gray theme to match a presentation style. I also need them to be fixed height, but the widths may vary depending on the length of the labels on the y-axis. When I try to export or save, there are always white side bars in the .jpg or .png file.

Here's some sample code that I use to create the chart (there are some extra theming controls in here that are superfluous to the simplified example, but the resulting chart is basically what I am generating):

```
library(ggplot2)
bar.font <- 8

title <- "Example"
l_labs <- c("")
x_labs <- c("A","B","C")
ests <- c(.5,.3,.2)
nerrs <- c(.05, .05, .05)
perrs <- nerrs

barchart.data <- data.frame(l_labs, x_labs, ests, nerrs, perrs)
p <- ggplot(barchart.data, aes(x=x_labs, y=ests*100)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color="#808080", position=position_dodge(), width=0.85, fill="#808080") +
  geom_text(aes(y=ests*100+perrs*100+1.5, label=sprintf("%1.1f%%", 100*ests)), vjust=0.5, hjust=0, size=bar.font, color="white") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=ests*100-nerrs*100, ymax=ests*100+perrs*100), width=.2, position=position_dodge(.9), color="white", size=0.25) + 
  labs(title=title, x="", y = "") + theme_classic() + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),limits = c(0,115), breaks=c(0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100)) + 
  theme(legend.position="none", legend.text = element_text(color = "white")) +
  theme(title = element_text(size=18, colour = "white")) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size=20, color = "white"), axis.line = element_line(color = "white")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(margin=margin(9,0,0,0)),axis.text.y = element_text(margin=margin(0,9,0,0))) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size=20, color = "white")) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(10,0,0,0))) +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_line(colour = 'white', size = .5)) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#1e1e1e")) +
  theme(legend.justification=c(1,0), legend.position=c(1,0)) +
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#1e1e1e", color = "#1e1e1e")) +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_line(colour = "white",size=0.1, linetype = "dotted"))

ggsave("test.jpg", height=10, units="in")
```

And here is what the exported .jpg looks like. I cannot specify an exact width because I do not know what it will be for each chart as the widths vary. Thanks for any guidance.

[image: Example image of exported chart using ggsave()]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the background color to whatever value you like:

```
ggsave("test.jpg", height=10, units="in", bg = "#1e1e1e")
```

[image]

This takes care of the white bars.

It may be a bit confusing that the `bg` option is not mentioned in the `ggsave()` documentation. That's because it's part of the graphics device, here `jpeg()`. It is mentioned in the `jpeg()` documentation.

The reason why there are white bars in the first place is discussed in depth in [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47703716/4975218)