# Shiny keeps empty blanc space when plots are not rendered

Tags: r, shiny

**Context:** a shiny app allows user to choose to display or not tables and graphs.

**Problem:** UI keeps a big white "placeholder" space for plots if they are not displayed (this behaviour is not wanted). But, when it comes to tables, UI doesn't display this empty white space (expected behaviour).

**Question:** How to prevent Shiny from keeping empty placeholder for plots?

**Previous researches:** This question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56839803/how-can-i-eliminate-placeholder-white-space-from-shiny-apps) but the answer by @the-mad-statter doesn't fits my needs. I would like to understand why Shiny has this behaviour and if possible correct it without changing the UI.

Many thanks for yout help! Please find below a reproductible example and some screenshots.

**Reproductible example**

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

# basic user interface
ui <- fluidPage(
    checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "checkboxes", label = NULL ,choices = list("Plot"="plot", "Table"="table")),
    plotOutput(outputId = "plotdf1"),
    tableOutput(outputId = "tabledf"),
    plotOutput(outputId = "plotdf2")
)

# server side calculations
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    df = mtcars
    output$plotdf1 = renderPlot({
      if("plot"%in%input$checkboxes){
      ggplot(data = df, aes(x = disp, y = qsec)) +
        geom_line()
      }
    })

    output$tabledf = renderTable({
      if("table"%in%input$checkboxes){
      df[1:5,]
      }
    })
    output$plotdf2 = renderPlot({
      if("plot"%in%input$checkboxes){
        ggplot(data = df, aes(x = gear)) +
          geom_bar()
      }
    })

}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

**Screenshots:**
All objects displayed:

[image: all objects]

When the table is removed the UI "fill"/removes the space left empty

[image: table ok]

But when plots are removed, empty placeholder remains

[image: plot not ok]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1. Using `conditionalPanel`**

You can use a `conditionalPanel` to hide the plot area when `Plot` is not selected:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "checkboxes", label = NULL, 
                     choices = list("Plot"="plot", "Table"="table")),
  conditionalPanel(
    "input.checkboxes.indexOf('plot') > -1",
    plotOutput(outputId = "plotdf1")
  ),
  tableOutput(outputId = "tabledf"),
  conditionalPanel(
    "input.checkboxes.indexOf('plot') > -1",
    plotOutput(outputId = "plotdf2")
  )
)
```

**2. Using `renderUI()`**

As suggested in comments section, another approach with `renderUI()`:

Modifications are much more important than in the 1st idea but if it fails this one might be a good alternative.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

# basic user interface
ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput(
    inputId = "checkboxes",
    label = NULL ,
    choices = list("Plot" = "plot", "Table" = "table")
  ),
  uiOutput(outputId = "uiplotdf1"),
  uiOutput(outputId = "uitabledf"),
  uiOutput(outputId = "uiplotdf2")
)

# server side calculations
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  df = mtcars
  # create the object to render and the conditional UI display anlong with it
  # 1st plot------------------
  # object
  output$plotdf1 = renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = df, aes(x = disp, y = qsec)) +
      geom_line()
  })
  # conditional UI
  output$uiplotdf1 = renderUI({
    if ("plot" %in% input$checkboxes) {
      plotOutput(outputId = "plotdf1")
    }
  })
  # table----------------------
  output$tabledf = renderTable({
    df[1:5, ]
  })
  output$uitabledf = renderUI({
    if ("table" %in% input$checkboxes) {
      tableOutput(outputId = "tabledf")
    }
  })
  #2nd plot---------------------
  output$plotdf2 = renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = df, aes(x = gear)) +
      geom_bar()
  })
  output$uiplotdf2 = renderUI({
    # this render is not pulled with the 1st one bcse otherwise we have to put plots in a "bigger" element (such as fluidrow)
    if ("plot" %in% input$checkboxes) {
      plotOutput(outputId = "plotdf2")
    }
  })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, this is working. Do you know why Shiny is having this behaviour? I have multiple checkboxes and adding all these conditional panels will be quite long...

Comment: I have to uncheck it as answer bcse it created some problems. `conditionalPanels()` require javascript condition that add rules to follow for each id name. Do you think it is possible to improve it in order not to add UI panels and constraints on objects ids?

Comment: @Paul What about a `renderUI` which renders the plot when `Plot` is selected and which  renders `NULL` otherwise?

Comment: I am currently working on this suggestion. It adds a lot of code; for each checkbox we have to create this structure: ui side: `uioutput("id1")` and server side: `output$id2 = renderPlot({...})` along with `output$id1 = renderUI(if(condition on checkboxes){plotOuput(id2)}) `.

Comment: In the end it produces the expected outcome, but still I do not understand that behaviour of adjusting the UI in case of table not displayed but not when plots are not displayed

Comment: @Paul `plotOutput` produces a `div` with a width and a length, it is empty in this case but it takes some space.